# Retrain a BERT Model

Tags: nlp, pytorch, text-classification, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model

I have trained a BERT model using pytorch for about a million text data for a classification task. After testing this model with new data I get False Positives and False Negatives. Now I want retrain the existing model only with FN and FP. I do not want to append the FN and FP to the exisiting dataset and then train the entire model again. How do I retrain this bert model only with these FN and Fp over the previosuly trained model.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the code for your train loop, the idea should look something like this after training:

```
results = model(data)
wrong_datapoints = []
for i, result in enumerate(results)

    if result != labels[i]:
        wrong_datapoints.append((data[i],labels[i]))


(data_new, labels_new) = list(zip(*wrong_datapoints))

model.train(data_new, labels_new)
```

If you want something more specific, you're going to have to provide code of your current train loop.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. But I want to keep a model version of it, since we train it every week, we model version it. And also iterating a million records will take a lot of time. I was thinking of loading the previous version of bin file(v1.0) and then retrain this with only new datapoints to create another version v2.0

Comment: You might want to clarify your question to state that. However, doing versioning does not remove the need to track the outcomes of data points after training, requiring a single loop over the train data after training is done. You need to determine what the "new datapoints" are, after all.